# $rootScope.$apply() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing an api call using angular service "AzureMobileClient " inside angular run method as follow:

```
myModule.run(function ($rootScope, $localStorage, AzureMobileClient, Data) {
//Return user json object; store it in Data.customerUserJsonObject
AzureMobileClient.getCustomerUser(function (item) {

    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        Data.customerServerRowObject = item;
        console.log("rootScope applied");
    });

    console.log("myModule.run: item >");
    console.log(item);}, $localStorage.phonenumber);

});
```

Notice that I have a data sharing service "Data" passed to the run method to store the retrieved item from the api callback.
The object "Data.customerServerRowObject" get set by the api call correctly. Also see the $rootScope.$apply() being called inside the callback to sync the object cross the angular application. Now, whenever I try to retrieve the object "Data.customerServerRowObject" in my controller I get "undefined" value:

```
controllers.OrderVarification = function ($scope, Data) {

// ng-model="customerPhonenumber" in the view
$scope.customerPhonenumber = Data.customerServerRowObject.phonenumber;

}
```

This is because the code inside the controller get executed while the api callback is still not done. I am also doing $rootSope.$apply() which has no effect in my run function

Comment: The run block will not wait for the `getCustomerUser` function to finish, so my guess is that the controller code is executed before `Data.customerServerRowObject` is set. So when the controller copies `phonenumber` it's `undefined`.

Comment: Also note that since `phonenumber` is a primtive its value is copied into `customerPhonenumber`. An update to `customerPhonenumber` at a later time will not update the value of `phonenuber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use promises, you can't convert an asynchronous operation in synchronous just by using $apply:

```
myModule.run(function ($rootScope, $localStorage, AzureMobileClient, Data, $q) {
//Return user json object; store it in Data.customerUserJsonObject
var deferred = $q.defer();
Data.customerServerRowObject = deferred.promise;
AzureMobileClient.getCustomerUser(function (item) {

    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        deferred.resolve(item);
        console.log("rootScope applied");
    });

    console.log("myModule.run: item >");
    console.log(item);}, $localStorage.phonenumber);

});


controllers.OrderVarification = function ($scope, Data) {
  // ng-model="customerPhonenumber" in the view
  Data.customerServerRowObject.then(function(data){
     $scope.customerPhonenumber = data.phonenumber;
  });
}
```

Comment: Best  practice: use `$timeout` instead of `$rootScope.$apply()` in order to avoid hard-to-debug error "digest already in progress"

Comment: You should *never* use $timeout for anything but: (1) business logic that has timeouts (2) by purpose async behaviour of the code. Rely on a fixed amount of time is not only inefficient, but is also unreliable.